# Filtering from 2 collections C#

Tags: c#

There are 2 collections. Coll A is items = {1,2,3,4,5}. Coll B = { 3, 6, 7 }
Need to find the common item and then remove all the other items from Coll A. So the result is this example should be Coll A = { 3 }.

Can you  a please let me know a Simple and elegant way..

Thanks

Comment: In the real world, we'd use `Intersect()`.  However, if this is homework s/he will probably not accept that... you'll have to put some thought into it and roll out your own ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can you use the LINQ `Intersect` method:

```
collectionA = collectionA.Intersect(collectionB).ToList();
```

Comment: Another instance is where I have a object and there is list of ID's that get passed. How do I remove the rows corresponding to these Id's

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#intersect1. LINQ provides a method called `Intersect` which operates the same as a mathematical intersection of two sets should.

Comment: Another instance is where I have a object and there is list of ID's that get passed. How do I remove the rows corresponding to these Id's

Comment: @Andy You really should be posting a new question. However, I think this should help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/c-using-linq-to-remove-objects-within-a-listt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/c-using-linq-to-remove-objects-within-a-listt)