# Lambda or LinQ expression to remove certain objects from List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I have a cart.Lines List and want to remove all items where quantity == 0

This is a list that holds collection of CartLine objects:

```
public class Cart
{
    private IList<CartLine> lines = new List<CartLine>();
    public IList<CartLine> Lines { get { return lines; } set { lines = value; } }
}   

public class CartLine
{
    Product Product {get; set;}
    int Quantity {get; set;}

}
```

So something like:

```
cart.Lines.RemoveAll(x => x.Quantity == 0)
```

**I only get Remove and RemoveAt, not RemoveAll !**

Also can't remove in a foreach loop, get error:
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

**I have now managed to do it with this code, surely there must be something more efficient ?**

```
var myList = cart.Lines.ToList();
myList.RemoveAll(x => x.Quantity == 0);
cart.Lines = myList;
```

**Okay Problem solved!Thanks guys, this here does it:**

**cart.Lines = cart.Lines.Where(x => x.Quantity != 0);**

Comment: It looks like a ToList()/RemoveAll() combo may even be the most efficient...  (see the timings below), but BARELY.  The Where() on negative condition followed by ToList() is nearly as fast.  I think the thing is RemoveAll() is very optimized for List<T>, so it's extremely fast where the other Linq methods using iterators (yield return) which tend to be a bit slower.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If Lines is a `List<T>`, then the simplest way is to just write:

```
cart.Lines.RemoveAll(x => x.Quantity == 0);
```

If Lines is an `IEnumerable<T>`, though, you could select the negative (as Vlad suggested) - you could also change to a list using `ToList()` and then do `RemoveAll()` but that would be overkill.

```
cart.Lines = cart.Lines.Where(x => x.Quantity != 0);
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you said Lines is an `IList<T>`, then you will want to select the negative and convert to a list like:

```
cart.Lines = cart.Lines.Where(x => x.Quantity != 0).ToList();
```

Or you can conver to a `List<T>` using `ToList()` then call `RemoveAll()` and then save back:

```
var temp = cart.Lines.ToList();
temp.RemoveAll(x => x.Quantity != 0);
cart.Lines = temp;
```

Incidentally, as an FYI I timed both building a remove list and then using `Remove()` vs selecting the negative using `Where()` and calling `ToList()` and the Where/ToList combo was much faster which makes sense because both allocate memory, but the Where/ToList does a lot less memory shuffling.

Here's the timing for removing all the even numbers out of a list of 100,000 ints:

- Removing all evens building a remove list and calling Remove() on each took: 3921 ms
- Removing all evens using Where() on negative and then ToList() took: 2 ms
- Removing all evens using ToList() on original then RemoveAll() took: 1 ms

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that cart.Lines is List<>: `cart.Lines.RemoveAll(x => x.Quantity == 0);`

Comment: So use `cart.Lines = cart.Lines.Where(x => x.Quantity > 0).ToList()`

Comment: @LaserBeak - Why exactly are you using interface collection instead of the generic List collection?

Comment: @Ramhound, he's probably trying to decouple the implementation a bit from the interface.  A lot of code analysis tools tend to recommend using IList<T> or ICollection<T> instead of List<T> directly.  Not saying that's necessarily good or bad, just something that comes up a lot.  Yeah, he added the IList<T> clarification in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myResult = cart.Lines.Where(x => x.Quantity > 0)
```

Alternatively you can use [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)

```
cart.Lines.RemoveAll(x => x.Quantity == 0)
```

Check this post that answers your question [C# using LINQ to remove objects within a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/c-using-linq-to-remove-objects-within-a-listt)

Answer (score 1):

These queries essentially foreach over a list, and as you know, you shouldn't use them to directly modify the list. Rather you should make a list of the items to be removed using the query, and then remove them in a separate operation.

EDIT:

yeh, I forgot you can use RemoveAll to do this in one line :D

Answer (score 1):

I will go ahead and post my suggestion to this problem.

```
private IList<CartLine> lines = new List<CartLine>();
```

should be:

```
private List<CartLine> lines = new List<CartLine>();
```

This will allow you to use the suggested method of:

```
cart.Lines.RemoveAll(x => x.Quantity == 0);
```

You do exactly that by doing it this way:

```
var myList = cart.Lines.ToList();       
myList.RemoveAll(x => x.Quantity == 0);              
cart.Lines = myList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
Cart cart = new Cart();
List<CartLine> cartLines = cart.Lines.ToList<CartLine>();
cartLines.RemoveAll(x => x.Quantity == 0);
cart.Lines = cartLines;
```

Also, you should set the CartLine Quantity and Product properties as public.