# Create new list from a old list using a lambda function

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have the following: `List<InputRow>` which contains a number of InputRow objects.

I am wondering if there is a way for me to use a lambda function on my original list to give me a new List where `InputRow.someProperty > 1` for all the objects.

This would leave me with a list of InputRow objects all having someProperty greater than 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using LINQ to remove objects within a List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-objects-within-a-listt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use LINQ (a conjunction of the [`.Where()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) and [.ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension methods):

```
List<InputRow> originalList = ...
List<InputRow> filteredList = originalList
    .Where(x => x.someProperty > 1)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Using `RemoveAll` on the List avoids deleting and re-creating the list.

Comment: @Servy Baxter wants those results not remove them

Comment: @Servy Can you elaborate on the usage of RemoveAll?  I could flip the statement to say RemoveAll less than or equal to 1.  I am just not sure what the syntax for that would be.

Comment: list.RemoveAll(x => x.SomeProperty<=1);

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal You can either logically refactor the lambda to mean the opposite (simple enough in this case), or you can just add a NOT outside of the whole thing to cover the general case.

Comment: To turn true into false just add !        list.RemoveAll(x => !(x.SomeProperty<=1));

Comment: Excellent, thank you for all the great answers / comments on this.  I have a much better idea of how to use those now.

Answer (score 7):

You can of course also do this:

```
var list = new List<string>(){ "a", "b", "c" };

list.RemoveAll(s => s == "b");
```

which removes the items in place instead of creating a new list.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You can do this:

```
var newList = inputRowList.Where(inputRow => inputRow.someProperty > 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<InputRow> newlist = oldlist.Where(x => x.someProperty > 1).ToList();
```

This will search your old list on the condition that `someProperty > 1` and convert the result into List using `.ToList()`