# Remove an item from a LINQ collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, linq

I think I am putting my question correctly :)

I am querying the database using LINQ to retrieve some data. Please find the code below.

```
var leadtasktype = _context.LeadTypeTaskTypes.Where(l => l.LeadTypeId == item.Value);

foreach(LeadTypeTaskType l in leadtasktype){
    if (l.TaskTypeId == 21)
    {
        //I need to remove an item which has the tasktype id 21
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in the comments, I need to remove items from the leadtasktype based on my `if` condition. How do I do this?

Comment: Look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-objects-within-a-listt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var leadtasktype = _context.LeadTypeTaskTypes.Where(l => l.LeadTypeId == item.Value && l.LeadTypeId != 21);
```

Answer (score 5):

This would seem very like another filter condition:

```
var leadtasktype = _context.LeadTypeTaskTypes
    .Where(l => l.LeadTypeId == item.Value)
    .Where(l => l.TaskTypeId != 21); // Exclude ID = 21.
```

Answer (score 3):

Just leave them out of your set:

```
var leadtasktype = _context.LeadTypeTaskTypes
    .Where(l => 
        l.leadTypeId != 21 && 
        l.LeadTypeId == item.Value
    );
```

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that for LINQ to Objects this approach is slightly faster than chaining `.Where()` methods, since less iterators are going to be used. For LINQ to SQL on the other hand, the same SQL code should be generated so it makes no real difference apart from style and readability (I myself like chaining better).

Answer (score 2):

```
var leadtasktype = _context.LeadTypeTaskTypes
    .Where(l => l.LeadTypeId == item.Value 
                && l.TaskTypeId != 21); // Exclude ID = 21.
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it this what you want ?

```
var leadtasktype = _context.LeadTypeTaskTypes.RemoveAll
   (l => l.LeadTypeId == item.Value && l.LeadTypeId == 21);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var leadtasktype = _context.LeadTypeTaskTypes.Where(l => l.LeadTypeId == item.Value);

var newData = leadtasktype;

                foreach(LeadTypeTaskType l in leadtasktype){
                    if (l.TaskTypeId == 21)
                    {
                        newData.Remove(l);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You cannot modify a collection in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: o please forgive me for this, Colorado and Washington just have passed the Marijuana legalization... so i feel a little bit high now.. = }

Answer (score 1):

```
var leadtasktype = _context.LeadTypeTaskTypes.Where(l => l.LeadTypeId == item.Value);

for (var i = 0; i < leadtasktype.Count; i++)
{
  if (leadtasktype[i].TaskTypeId == 21)
  {
    leadtasktype.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: you should not do that. this will kill your performance on large lists.