# remove all strings from list containing certain substring

Tags: c#, list

I've got a list of strings called albumList
the string has this structure: abc,abc,abc,abc,abc
I ask the user to search an album to delete; if the album is found, it will be deleted from the list. There could be more than one album with the same name to be deleted from the list.

```
 private void searchAlbumName(string search)
        {
            string[] cellVal;
            foreach (string x in albumList)
            {
                cellVal = x.Split(',');
                if (cellVal[0].ToString().Equals(search))
                {
                    //do delete here
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure how to remove every album with the search name

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) to get the result:

```
albumList.RemoveAll(x => x.Split(',')[0].ToString().Equals(search))
```

For easier to read, you can use:

```
albumList.RemoveAll(x => x.Split(',').First().Equals(search))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `LINQ` do

```
albumList.RemoveAll(x => cellVal[0].ToString().Equals(search)));
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-objects-within-a-listt) post.