# Remove Item have same key in List C#

Tags: c#, list, removeall

I have a `List<Object>` n `Objects`.
In n Objects have some object that they have same `Id`.
Example `List<T> = {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5....,t10}.`

assuming that:

`t1.Id = t5.id`

So i want to remove `t5` from that `List`.

Who can help me plz.

In this question:  [using LINQ to remove objects within a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-objects-within-a-listt) you know that object duplicates (ex: "bob"), but in my question, in this List, i don't know any object duplicate before.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ to solve your problem? Show your effort first..

Comment: You might want to check out the [`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), unless your homework/assignment absolutely requires you to use `List` instead.

Comment: i'm new with LINQ. I tried with 2 for loop, but this solution not optimize.

Comment: If you need an optimal solution: This kind of problem is best solved with a `Dictionary` (as stated above). A `Dictionary` does not allow you to add multiple data with the same key and is extremely fast at finding a key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using LINQ to Objects only:

```
source = source.GroupBy(t => t.id).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 from me. Also correct, if you aren't lazy enough to use existing implementation)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I think it may be an overkill to load whole `moreLinq` assemble just for one `DistinctBy` call. That's why I posted the LINQ to Objects only answer first.

Comment: Wow. You are right that there is no Distinct(predicate). Of course there should be. And the reason I thought there was is of course because I created my own :D go figure.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [moreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) (get it from NuGet) extension `DistinctBy`

```
var result = list.DistinctBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the reason for downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there is no reason that `Distinct` will pick the first, as it is implemented using a hash set or similar. Since he specifically asked `t5` to be removed, you need to guarantee that. That was my initial reaction anyway. Dunno if that is why you were downvoted.

Comment: Actually, that is not true for `DistinctBy`. Perhaps that wasn't the reason for the down vote then.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen [DistnctBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs?r=d4396b9ff63932be0ab07c36452a481d20f96307) described as `If a key is seen multiple times, only the first element with that key is returned.`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You can look at [`DistinctBy` implementation](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) and you'll see it will return the first one.

Comment: Yes, I went and looked at the source, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list.RemoveAll(input => list.Count(i => i.Id == input.Id) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = items.GroupBy(item => item.Id).Select(item2 => item2.First()).ToList();
```