# Remove items from list where a match is found

Tags: c#, concatenation

I have 2 lists `ListOfItemsToControl` and `lstRemoveItems`. I want to remove `ListOfItemsToControl`  where `lstRemoveItems.sItemName` matches `ListOfItemsToControl.sItemName`

How can this be done ?

Comment: i can add 2 lists using concatenation and i know that i can loop through the list but there must be a single line of LINQ code to do the job

Comment: As usual, Jon Skeet has answered this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-objects-within-a-listt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a LINQ one-liner.  I haven't tested this, but it should work:

```
ListOfItemsToControl = ListOfItemsToControl.Where(l => !lstRemoveItems.Any(r => r.sItemName == l.sItemName)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var names = lstRemoveItems.Select(y => y.sItemName).ToList();
var result = ListOfItemsToControl.Where(x => names.Contains(x.sItemName)).ToList();
var resultList = ListOfItemsToControl.Except(result);
```

That seems *odd* but it should work :)