# find elements of different types in two lists with common property value, linq variant of two for each loops

Tags: vb.net, performance, linq, list, iequalitycomparer

there are two lists

1. Myobjects list contains all items, all have property "oid" of
   ObjectID
2. The list of ObjectID types is list of **ALL** objects to be
   deleted

Problem is to find any item in Myobjects that has ObjectID in oid property.
I'm having a hard time finding equivalent of this two "for each" loops in LINQ.
This should be easy, but I'm doing it wrong. It takes 20 sec to perform this LINQ on 30 000 items, and under one sec using for-each loop. Below is working **for-each** loop, and my attempt to make **LINQ** of it (this one is slow). Linq solution is what I would like to have.

```
        For Each i As LengthAreaObject In myobjects
            For Each o As ObjectId In oidsToRem
                If i.oid = o Then
                    returnlist.Add(i)
                    oidsToRem.Remove(o)
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next
        Next
```

and LINQ attempt here

```
Dim rlist As List(Of LengthAreaObject) = (From i As LengthAreaObject In myobjects.AsParallel Where oidsToRem.Contains(i.oid) Select i).ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

How much items have the collections?

For small collections, AsParallel will be slower because of the extra method call.

Comment: about 20 000 to 40 000 items (i will modify question)

Answer (score 0):

I have found similiar question [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-elements-from-a-listt?rq=1) and modified it.
So the solution to speed things up is nothing more but to hash collection where the objects are you test for "contains". Otherwise, contains is slow!

```
Dim setToRemove = New HashSet(Of ObjectId)(oidstoRem)
   Dim returnlist As List(Of LengthAreaObject) = lengthAreaList.AsParallel.Where(Function(x) setToRemove.Contains(x.oid)).ToList
```