# Remove item from List<T> if a nested collection contains specified value

Tags: c#

I have basically achieved my desired effect through a not so elegant foreach loop. I am posting here for two reasons. One is if someone can show me a "cool" kid way to do it and or comment on reality as sometimes a foreach over an array is faster then casting to a List then using Lambda expressions.

So I am working with ExtendedAttributes property on the Artifact class.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.artifact(v=vs.110).aspx

```
//I get my array of artifacts just fine

LinkFilter linkFilter = new LinkFilter();
linkFilter.FilterType = FilterType.ToolType;
linkFilter.FilterValues = new String[1] { ToolNames.WorkItemTracking }; //only work itms

Artifact[] artifacts = linkingService.GetReferencingArtifacts(changesetArtifactUris.ToArray(), new LinkFilter[1] { linkFilter });

//now I want to keep work items that are resolved or closed
//so I cast put into a List<T> just to then use Lambda in a for each loop
//THIS SECTION PSEUDO CODE FOR BREVITY yes I know you can't modify object you are looping over
var lst_artifacts = new List<Artifact>(artifacts);
foreach (var item in lst_artifacts)
{
   lst_artifacts.RemoveAt(item.ExtendedAttributes.ElementAt(y => y.Value != "Resolved" || y.Value != "Closed"));
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: CodeReview SE may be more appropriate for this kind of question... Note that LINQ is generally not useful for removal of items (as opposed to filter + ToList)... On other hand removal of items one-by-one is likely slower than filter and recreate list - try and measure.

Comment: CodeReview SE..should have known something like that would have existed but never thought to check. Thanks

Comment: I'd post the whole method on CR though, not just a snippet; Code Review folks like to see the full context and comment on any and all aspects of the code (that's actually in their Help Center rules for on-topicness). See you there!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-elements-from-a-listt?rq=1

Comment: @KenHung The link was educational as to the wisdom of HashSets so Thank You. But my dilemma is with the nested collection being where I make my filter determination.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: Not a cool kid.

What about using [`.Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb910018(v=vs.90).aspx) with a invert of your existing predicate:

```
authorsList = authorsList.Where(x => x.ExtendedAttributes.ElementAt(y => y.Value == "Resolved" || y.Value == "Closed")).ToList();
```

**EDIT**: Added `.ToList()` as I always forget it, thanks to @KyleJV

Comment: Don't forget .ToList()

Comment: Thanks @KyleJV. I **always** forget It returns a generic `IEnumberable<T>` rather than a `List<T>`

Comment: Hold on, isn't the OP looking to remove the selected values?  We probably would want opposite logic, not that two != operators on an "OR" isn't probably going to give odd results.  Ex: value as "Resolved" would return true since it is not equal to "Closed"

Comment: Gawd... Right again. Sometimes, I wonder if I should answer questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are struggling on which function to use. You should use `Any()` instead of `ElementAt()`, your lambda `y => y.Value != "Resolved" || y.Value != "Closed"` is not a number, you cannot pass it into `ElementAt()`. You can use `ElementAt(1)`, `ElementAt(2)` to get the element at specific index, but not `ElementAt(true)`.

```
lst_artifacts.RemoveAll(item => !item.ExtendedAttributes.Any(y => y.Value == "Resolved" || y.Value == "Closed"));
```

It will remove all the items which do not have any resolved or closed attributes.