# How to delete all the specified contents from an object in a list in C#

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list that looks like the following:

```
STUDENT: John, TEST ONE: A, TEST TWO: A, TEST THREE: D
STUDENT: Greg, TEST ONE: F, TEST TWO: B, TEST THREE: D
```

How can I delete the data for a specific student once the user inputs the name?
I've tried doing the following but it doesn't work:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>(); // contains the list of students that
                                       //  were appended
```

Then, inside of a method here is some of the code that I wrote:

```
Console.Write("Enter the name of the student you want to remove: ");
string removedStudent = Console.ReadLine();
list.RemoveAll(s => s == removedStudent);
```

When the code runs and I input `Greg` as the name of the student I want to remove, nothing happens. I print the list and Greg is still in the list. So, instead of printing like this:

```
STUDENT: John, TEST ONE: A, TEST TWO: A, TEST THREE: D
```

It still prints like:

```
STUDENT: John, TEST ONE: A, TEST TWO: A, TEST THREE: D
STUDENT: Greg, TEST ONE: F, TEST TWO: B, TEST THREE: D
```

Is there a way I can delete the entire row just by specifying the name of the student?

Edit:

Here is the part where I ask the user to input the student information:

```
class StudentsIO
{
    public object getInput()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter student name: ");
        string studentName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter test 1 score: ");
        string test1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter test 2: ");
        string test2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter test 3: ");
        string test3 = Console.ReadLine()
        Students students = new Students(studentName,test1,test2,test3);
        return students;
    }
}
```

Here's where I add students to the list:

```
StudentIO newStudent = new StudentIO();
object studentList = newStudent.getInput();
list.Add(studentList);
```

Comment: Why is it a list of object instead of a list of Student?

Comment: What is the content of `removedStudent` ??

Comment: Linq should be 
`list.RemoveAll(s => s.STUDENT == removedStudent);`

Comment: @RonBeyer I originally did have it as Student instead of object but my code threw a bunch of error, specifically when I tried appending a new student. It started working when I changed it to object.

Comment: If you were getting errors when appending to `List<Student>` that is another issue that you need to address. It is seldom, if ever, a good idea to use `List<object>`. If you find a need to use `List<object>`, it usually means something is wrong with your design.

Comment: @joanne72205 Can you show us what you are doing when you are adding students? Are you, perchance, typing `list.Add("Greg")`? I'm wondering if you are inadvertently creating a list of strings _as objects_ instead of adding Student objects to your list.

Comment: @AndyPalmer I added an edit where I copied some of the code that I used to ask the user various questions and then where I save it to the list.

Comment: The signature of your method should be `public Students getInput()` and your assignment should be `Students studentLIst = newStudent.getInput()` or simply `var studentList = newStudent.getInput()`. Then you could have a `List<Students>`.

Comment: @TBurnside Your suggestion completely fixed all my problems! It makes sense now that I'm looking at the code with your edit and I don't know why I didn't implement it in the first place.

Comment: @joanne72205, are you going to accept any of the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as Ron Beyer implies in his comment, you should be using something more specific than `List<object>`. I'm not sure what data type your students are, but let's say they are a class Student, with a STUDENT property that specifies the name. You would then have `List<Student>`.

Since the list contains objects (not Students), `1ist.removeAll(s => s == removedStudent)` is using the == operator defined on object, which does object comparison. The string you entered is NOT the same object as the Student in the list. If you have a `List<Student>`, you would then use:

```
list.removeAll(s => s.STUDENT == removedStudent);
```

to remove the student from the list.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what your object looks like from your question, but have you tried something like this?

```
list.RemoveAll(s => s.STUDENT == removedStudent);
```

[Answered here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853551/2097243)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
students.RemoveAll(s => string.Compare(s.Name, studentNameToRemove, true) == 0);
```