# Filter List By items in Array (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of `Fruit`:

```
List<Fruit>
```

where `Fruit` has the following properties/fields:

```
id
name
color
```

Given an array of integers:

```
int[] ids = new [] {1,2,8};
```

How can I filter my list so that it will exclude the fruits whose `id` is in the array?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll get more responses here if you can show some code (even if it's not working).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LINQ to remove elements from a List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-elements-from-a-listt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var l = new List<Fruit>();
var exceptions = new int[] {1,2,8};
var filtered = l.Where(x=> !exceptions.Contains(x.id));
```

Note that this will return a new filtered `IEnumerable<Fruit>`; it will not remove the items from the original list. To actually remove them from the list, you can use instead:

```
l.RemoveAll(x => exceptions.Contains(x.id));
```