# How to RemoveAll list rows matching a condition using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, removeall

I'm trying to remove all records in a `List<T>` matching a where condition. What I did find in linq is the `RemoveAll()` method but it seems to only work by removing properties matching a condition instead of the `complete row` in the list.

So I did try a remove all as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-elements-from-a-listt)  in conjunction with a Where clause which causes an `"argument null exception".`

**Question:**

How can you RemoveAll list rows matching a condition using linq?

```
//Sort the list by the UpdatedTime time descending
//Remove all records in list that are older than today's date and status equal to BB. Then order the remaining records desc.
var cuttOff = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-10);
List<Escalation> escHistorySorted = escHistory.RemoveAll.Where(x => x.UpdatedTime  <= cuttOff && x.status == "BB").OrderByDescending(d => d.UpdatedTime).ToList();
```

Comment: **Invert the condition** ? So, **List<Escalation> escHistorySorted = escHistory.Where(x => !(x.UpdatedTime  <= cuttOff && x.status == "BB"))** . Or maybe I didn't get what you are asking here :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do too much at once.

Remove the records first (move the predicate from your `where` clause directly inside `RemoveAll`), and then sort them.

```
var cuttOff = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-10);

escHistory.RemoveAll(x => x.UpdatedTime <= cuttOff && x.status == "BB");

List<Escalation> escHistorySorted = escHistory.OrderByDescending(d => d.UpdatedTime).ToList();
```

The return value of `RemoveAll` is an integer representing the number of records removed, so you can't simply order the result of calling that method.

Comment: Ok that makes sense as I can't call OrderByDescending on the int result of RemoveAll.