# Remove lines from List<String[]> using Linq, if meeting a certain criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I've searched around for a solution to this question but can't find an applicable circumstance and can't get my head around it either.

I've got a `List<String[]>` object (a parsed CSV file) and want to remove any rows if the first value in the row is equal to my criteria.

I've tried the following (with variations) and can't seem to get it to delete the lines, it just passes over them:

```
rows.RemoveAll(s => s[0].ToString() != "Test");
```

Which I'm currently reading as, remove `s` if `s[0]` (the first value in the row) does not equal "Test".

Can someone point me in the right direction for this?

Thanks, Al.

**Edit for wider context / better understanding:**

The code is as  follows:

```
  private void CleanUpCSV(string path)
    {

        List<string[]> rows = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();
        rows.RemoveAll(s => s[0] != "Test");

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false))
        {
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(row);
            }
        }
    }
```

So the question is -> Why won't this remove the lines that do not start with "Test" and upon writing, why is it returning System.String[] as all the values?

Comment: *'can't seem to get it to work'* - problem description is not clear

Comment: That expression should work, except that you shouldn't need `.ToString()`, unless you don't actually have strings. Also, you need to explain what happens when you try that code. Does it remove everything? Nothing? Wrong values, if so which ones?

Comment: Thats not linq by the way.

Comment: Try : rows.Where(s => s[0] != "Test").ToList();  Your query should be "==" not "!=".

Comment: It sounds like you have each csv line as an item in the list. You would need a list of lists if the lines were parsed into tokens.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen removed .ToString() and writing to a file, it replaces all with System.String[] as the value

Comment: **What exactly is the question?** Are you asking how to remove lines from a list using a predicate or are you asking why the output of your writer loop ends up writing lines containing only "System.String[]"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LINQ to remove elements from a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-elements-from-a-listt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with `Where`? `Where` is going to filter based on a predicate. You should be able to do something like this:

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDBasMwDD3HXyF8SqAzu2fppbDB6GCwQg8hB89TW0NqbZbbMkK@PZOzDkaFQDxJ7/Ekx3eOIk7TiX3Yw9s3JzzW6j8yK@p7dMlTYPOEAaN3NxtrH75qVeRQn6f33jtwvWWG10j7aI9qUMW1z8kmKWfyH/BifSgrVci0WHtOD5yiqLbdEiJdGBoIeIGbyTA3227QG@Skx8UfBv1IpEcYs5MrPxezPWDEUuASuL3voGngl1uZDWX1ssoUyZ28wrpDebYxU8GHWUEszh6LlbyAejTb6BPK0aI6@zLPJJfohV7k/aqqs9ioJMdp@gE)

```
    List<string[]> rows = new List<string[]> { new []{"Test"}, new []{ "Foo"} };
    rows = rows.Where(s => s[0] == "Test").ToList();

    foreach(var row in rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row));   
    }
```

output

```
Test
```

- You dont need `ToString()` because S[0] is already a string
- You may want to handle empty case or s[0] could throw
- You can use s.First() instead of s[0]
- You can learn more about `Predicate`on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

### Edit

For your example:

```
private void CleanUpCSV(string path)
{

    var rows = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(x => x.Split(','));

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false))
    {
        foreach (var row in rows.Where(s => s[0] == "Test"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row));
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, you may want to use a library to handle csv parsing. I personally use [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper)

Comment: Thank you aloisdg and @CSharpie Working as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

The only error in your code is the following:

Since row is `string[]` this

```
writer.WriteLine(row);
```

won't give you the result you were expecting.

Change it like this

```
writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", row));
```

To convert the `string[]`back into its orginal form.

Any other "optimisation" in all the answers proposed here arent really optimal either.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really trying to remove items where the first element isn't "Test", then your code should work, though you don't need to call .ToString() on s[0] since it's already a string. If this doesn't work for you, perhaps your problem lurks elsewhere? If you give an example of your code in a wider context you could get more help

Answer (score 0):

Filter it like this instead:

```
var filteredList = rows.Where(s => s[0] == "test").ToArray();
```