# C# How to remove object form list using keyword?

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections

I have this code

```
 monthly[i] = new MonthlyEmployee();  
 monthly[i].ID = Console.ReadLine();
 monthly[i].Name = Console.ReadLine();
 monthly[i].Fee = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

 //Add to list
 listemployee.Add(mothly[i]);
```

I have another object which similar with this code and they are in the same list **Employee**. I want to add menu to remove the employee, but the user should input the ID. So, The user can choose which employee they want to remove. But, I don't know the way to access the employeee ID. Thanks, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it a `List<>`? Then maybe you can use `monthly.RemoveAll(e => e.ID == idToRemove);`. But maybe you should use a `Dictionary<,>` instead where the ID were the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `monthly.RemoveAll(x => x.ID == ID);`.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/853526/6527049) link, lot of good solutions can be found.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this to get the item first and then remove it

```
var itemToRemove = listemployee.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID);
if (itemToRemove != null)
    listemployee.Remove(itemToRemove);
```